# How can I re-create `default` connection in typeorm?

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I am using `TypeOrm` in my typescript object to create database connection: https://typeorm.io/#/connection-api. I am using the connection API directly rather than manager. The problem is that if I re-create the database connection at the second time, it will throw an exception:

```
await createConnection(params);


AlreadyHasActiveConnectionError: Cannot create a new connection named "default", because connection with such name already exist and it now has an active connection session
```

the reason I need to recreate is to use a different credential to create the connection.

How can I recreate the connection?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: I don't think typeorm supports it.

Comment: I had your same error, I managed to get the connection with the ‘ConnectionManager’ instead of creating it every time with the function ‘createConnection()‘.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express-based nodejs application and want to use middleware for your TypeOrm connection with any type of database. Then use the below code in your middleware file.

Middleware. ts

```js
    import * as express from 'express'; 
    import (createConnection, getConnectionManager) from "typeorm":

       export const dbConnection async (req:express.Request, 
          res:express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {

         if(!getConnectionManager().has("default")) {

           await createConnection();
          }

         next(); 
        }
```

ln index. ts add below lines

```js
    import {dbConnection} from '/.middleware.ts';
    import * as express from 'express';
    const app = express () ;
    app.use(dbConnection) ;
```